# Solar station gives almost no energy

Tags: usb, solar-cell, inverter

I have a solar station on my roof which I use for a raspberry pi. I also have a battery which seems very big for me - it looks like a car battery. The solar cell powers the battery and then the power cable goes over a charge controller to a power inverter.

Everything went fine until a few weeks ago suddenly the battery power was low and the system stopped working. Now, if I want to use my raspi, I have to load the battery for about 3 days before without using any of the power.

But this is strange: The raspi takes less than 5 W. Let's say the rest of the system takes about 45 W and the solar cell gives a half from the power it could give as a maximum. Then I would use *50 W* and have - 600W/2=*300W*! That should be enought for just a little raspi, shouldn't it?

So, have you any ideas what problem this could be? Maybe there is something wrong with the inverter? Thanks!

P.S.: I have European sockets, maybe they *must* give x watt so it is too much for my solar cell and the rest warms the usb converter?

P.P.S.: The inverter also has an USB output. Do you think I should try this?

Comment: What is the rest of the system? What else is connected? Doesn't any of it have any diagnostic LED's or meters? European sockets don't have a minimum power output.

Comment: There is a controller for it and a LAN cable connected to the raspi. Nothing else. The controller has a LCD display. Should not use much of the power. @lcy

Comment: What does it say on the LCD Display? What information is available through the LAN interface?

Comment: The LCD display tells me the battery state (%) and the LAN has nothing to do with the station, it's just for the raspi. @lcy

Comment: So no LED's to show charging / discharging state, current or power?

Comment: Also do you really have a 600W solar panel supplying only a raspberry pi?

Comment: Yeah, only one raspi, no status LED and 600 W. @lcy

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: @palsch probably lack of detail regarding the panel itself. Regardless the question was enough for an intelligent answer so I upvoted it.

Comment: @the one who voted down If you really need additional info, tell me, I'll go look for it.

Comment: You mention a solar panel and battery, but you don't mention a charge controller. Do you really have a 600W solar panel just connected straight to the battery?

Comment: @jwygralak67 no, sorry forgot it

Comment: Edited the question.

Comment: Could you give me the reason for the off-topic? Do you think I should post the question in the Physics forum?

Comment: "Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired."? What are you missing? Tell me!

Answer (score 2):

First, bear in mind that the solar panel will only work during the day.  Then allow for huge differences in output depending on the weather.  In direct sunlight, the panel should be generating close to its maximum.  In light cloud it may drop to 1/10 of that.  In heavy cloud, it will be even worse, perhaps 1/100 of the rated power.

Then allow for all the losses in your system.  The solar panel feeds a battery charger, which feeds a battery, which feeds an inverter, which feeds a power supply, which feeds your equipment.

The chances are that most of the power being generated by the panel will never even get to the Raspberry Pi.  The inverter may well be the component that's using the most power.

Comment: Yes, but I am using 5 W out of 0.1*600W=60W! I can't imagine that this is not enought.

Comment: Has it been very cloudy in your part of Europe lately?

Comment: Do you even need the inverter, if all it's supplying is a USB power supply?  You may be much better off with a simple USB power supply designed to run straight off the battery - if it's a 12V battery, this might be the sort intended for use in a car.

Comment: @lcy yes, but after the problem occurred. When it was sunny, it didn't work, too.

Comment: @Simon B Hm... I think that would be too complicated and unsecure.

Comment: You almost need some indicator on the charger. Is the charger even charging the battery?

Comment: It sounds like some fault-finding is required.  Is the charger working?  Is the battery dead?  Lead-acid batteries can be permanently damaged if they are left flat for long periods.  Is the inverter drawing so much power from the battery that it never charges properly?

Answer (score 1):

The most obvious answer is that your battery has gone bad. You don't say how old the system is, so there's no way to tell at this remove. The test you want to do is pretty straightforward. Disable/disconnect the inverter, and let the system charge for 3 days of bright weather (at this time of year, Europe doesn't get that much sun). Then connect the inverter and drive a low-power light bulb, and see how long it lasts. This should give you a good idea of the actual system capacity.

Another possibility is that, at this time of year, the total solar power you get in a day is just about how much the inverter draws with no load. With less than 10 hours of daylight (at 45 degrees latitude), and often with cloud cover, you may simply not be getting much power. The test I've indicated should tell you a lot.

Comment: The system is pretty new, a few months. I have already tried your solution, it worked for about a week.